# Download text or xml file with msi

Tags: download, windows-installer

I have a scenario where users can log into their account on the web and download an msi file which will self install an application after downloading. I however also want to download a text or xml file with the msi which will contain some account information which the install application will need after it installs. But user should however not be prompted for the download of the extra text file (better user experience). They should only need to click yes to download for the msi and thats it. Can anybody please suggest possible ways I can achieve this

Answer (score 0):

You could digitally water mark ( generate and apply a transform ) the MSI on the server before the user downloads it that way the file is already backed in.

Comment: Hi Christopher
Thanks for the reply but I have no idea what you mean by digitally water mark the msi. Can you please shed some more light on this

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_watermarking   Basically every person who downloads the MSI gets a slightly different one with the variation point already baked in.